# Data anntotation attributes. How to set order of execution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, data-annotations

I created validation attributes for the date of birth like this:

```
public class DateRequired : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
            return date != DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }

    public class DateGraterThanEighteen : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
            long ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks - date.Ticks;
            int years = new DateTime(ticks).Year;
            return years >= 18;
        }
    }

I applied attributes like this

        [DateGraterThanEighteen(ErrorMessage="You must be at least 18")]
        [DateRequired(ErrorMessage = "Date of birth is required")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

No matter the order i apply them, DateGraterThanEighteen executes first. How can i make DateRequired to execute first?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply orders to filters. Not sure if you can with validation attributes Try

```
[DateGraterThanEighteen(ErrorMessage="You must be at least 18"), Order=1]
[DateRequired(ErrorMessage = "Date of birth is required"), Order=2]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Just FYI, you misspelled greater :)

Update: Nevermind, can't do this. Yoou need to create a [ModelValidationProvider](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/enterprise-library-validation-example-for-aspnet-mvc-2.html).